# H2 - Oracle - liquibase - org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "all_sequences" not found;

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I try to add H2 for testing purpose into Spring Boot `application-test.yml`, my production Db is Oracle. I want to populate H2 schema by liquibase, but I receive following error:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "all_sequences" not
>   found; SQL statement:

My config is following:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: test
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;MODE=Oracle
    username: sa
    password:
    platform: h2
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    generate-ddl: true

  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /console

liquibase:
  url: ${spring.datasource.url}
  enabled: true
  user: sa
  password:
  change-log: classpath:liquibase/test-master.xml
  drop-first: true
```

How to adjust config aboive, I spent few hours, but can not figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding:

```
jpa:
  properties:
    hibernate:
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Solved problem.

Full config:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=Oracle
    username: sa
    password:
    platform: h2
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    generate-ddl: true

liquibase:
  url: ${spring.datasource.url}
  contexts: test
  change-log: classpath:liquibase/test-master.xml
  user: sa
  password:
```

Answer (score 1):

**all_sequences** is Oracle specific DB table. You should only migrate the user defined tables.

Comment: Could you give some hint, how to achieve that?